# why the div element can't occupy the whole line?

Tags: html, css

I have li elements and I change it's display to inline-block, while the div element can occupy a whole line.why ? It is also a block-level element, but the display prove I'm wrong,could you help me ?

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid ;
  
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
   <li>
     <div class="logo"></div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="logo"></div>
   </li>
   <li><div class="logo"></div>
   </li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: no ,I want to ask  why the div's border can't occupy the whole line?Because It's a block-level element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the list size to a certain width so the list element won't take up the entire width. If you want the element to take up the whole length of the page (which is what I assume you mean by whole line), set the width to 100%.

Edit: Forgot to set margin and padding of ul and li elements to 0.

Edit2: Might as well set body margin and padding to 0 too for good measure

```css
ul, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid ;
  
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
   <li><div class="logo"></div></li>
   <li><div class="logo"></div></li>
   <li><div class="logo"></div></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _but why the div don't take the entire width of the whole line?_

Comment: @jackhwwa That is because the div is nested within an inline-block li element. A block element always occupies all available width. And, that `available` width is li's width in your case. (... this answer explains that)

Comment: appriciate it !